# looking for a sample of MongoDB benchrun

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, benchmarking

I would like to run a benchmark using mongodb benchrun that will create a lot of load on the backend storage. and at the same time will be representative of real application workloads.
If somebody has some js code ready, would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take a look in MongoDB repository on github - there are multiple performance tests that use benchRun.  https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/tree/master/jstests has some in bench_xxx.js files.

You can also look at some sample scripts I have here: 
https://github.com/asya999/bits-n-pieces/tree/master/benchRun